apache-camel 4: route cxf not working :No resource classes found
we have this configuration that work fine in spring projet with java 8, camel 2 and CXF (cxf-rt-rs-client, cxf-rt-frontrnd-javaxrs 3.5.7)
<route id="monitorServiceRoute">
         <from
            uri="cxfrs:bean:monitorEndpoint?bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer" />
         <log message="REST monitor: ${header.operationName}"/>    
         <toD uri="direct:router-${header.operationName}"/>
      </route>

<bean id="monitorEndpoint"
      class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean">
      <property name="serviceClass"
         value="com.test.monitor.service.MonitorService" />
      <property name="address" value="/monitor" />
      <property name="providers">
         <list>
            <ref bean="provider" />
         </list>
      </property>    </bean>

passing to java 17, camel 4, CXF (cxf-rt-rs-client, cxf-rt-frontrnd-javaxrs 4.0.2), I add the lib Camel-cxf-rest to bypass an error of no endpoint.
But I have new one :
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: null
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:219)
    
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: No resource classes found
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.checkResources(AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:155)

I replace <property name="serviceClass" by <property name="resourceClasses" but I have the same error
Any idea please
